# Does GitHub count the commits you made that are in a private repo of an organization

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit

I have been contributing to a private repo of an organization on GitHub. There is no member added in the organization and at the organization page, it shows this message

> This organization has no public members. You must be a member to see who’s a part of this organization.

So, I am the part of this organization and I have made a few commits, verified by GPD signature verification but these commits are not being counted by my contribution heat map, even though I have checked the option to show contributions on the private repos. Does GitHub count the commits you made in a private repo of an org for your heatmap ?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#what-counts-as-a-contribution

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not private contributions are counted and shown on your profile is a setting in your GitHub profile. The default is to only show activity from public repositories (https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile)

> Your GitHub profile shows a graph of your repository contributions over the past year. You can choose to show anonymized activity from private and internal repositories in addition to the activity from public repositories.

Note that the e-mail address of the commits must be linked to your GitHub account (https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile):

> Note: Commits will only appear on your contributions graph if the email address you used to author the commits is connected to your account on GitHub. For more information, see "Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?"